# How can I enable comments on category page but not home page?

Tags: comments

I would like to enable user comments for posts in one category only, and only on the page for that category (category-$slug.php). Comments should not be enabled for those posts on the home page. What is a good strategy?

Do I need to do something like having two different template parts for posts, one that shows comments and one that doesn't?

Comment: Most themes rely on [`comments_open()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/comments_open/) to display a link to the post comments, so you can use the [`comments_open` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comments_open/) and conditional tags like [`in_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/#a-category-page) to disable the comments links - i.e. display no links to the comments for posts in that specific category.

Comment: Category pages can't have comments.